# How to save images to SD card to save app's space?

Tags: android, android-image, android-drawable

Here is my problem : I am developing an app that requires a lot of images. Now I want the images to be part of the APK file but I would very much like to move them all to SD card so my app isn't taking like 20-30Mb of phone's storage.
As for now images are all in `drawables` folder but I was wondering if there was anyway I could move them all to SD card (for example on first startup after install) and remove them from phone's storage ?

Maybe using `assets` ?

If any of you think of a great mechanism to achieve that, please tell me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not bundle your images with the app itself. Instead, download them when the user first launches your app and save them to the external Storage.

Even if you copy images from your Assets folder to the external storage, your app still takes up the same amount of space on Internal Storage as the assets folder cannot be modified after compilation. It is read only. So in reality you will end up with two copies of the same data, and consume even more space.

You could also look into allowing the user to [move your app to the external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html). Keep in mind that some applications cease to function properly when this is enabled and the external storage is unmounted.

Comment: Thanks Raghav. So if I understand your first solution correctly I have a very light app so that's great, but then I need a server or something to store the images and I'm kind of afraid that downloading 20-30Mb of pictures at first startup could cause some performances issues, also I will have to handle the case where the user is not connected at first launch or has a very slow connection, ...

Comment: @Pom12 Yes, you understood that correctly. It would be best to zip all the images and download them to save bandwidth and time

Comment: Yes, but it's still a pretty heavy process (both downloading the zip file and implementing all the backend to download the pictures, make sure the user received them all before giving him a real access to the app, ...), however the external storage install option seems a good idea, at least I will look further at this process, at least I can test it pretty quicly !

Comment: Plus I just had a quick look at Google's warnings regarding which kind of apps should not be installed on external storage and I think mine is pretty safe !

Comment: @Pom12 If yours is safe that way, then you should be fine :)